# Print the same string * x in reverse multiple times?

Tags: python

So in order to solve an exercise I need to print the string "X" * user input value like this :

```
XXXXXXXX
 XXXXXXX
  XXXXXX
   XXXXX
    XXXX
     XXX
      XX
       X
```

My code does this:

```
XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXX
XXXX
XXX
XX
X
```

I've tried this function but obliviously it's not doing what I need, it's just inverting character by character :

```py
x = int(input())
times = x
def reverse(s): 
  str = " " 
  for i in s: 
    str = i + str
  return str

for x in range(x):
    s=((times - x ) *" X"  )
    print(reverse(s))
```

This is my original code I've made so far without the function to reverse

```py
x = int(input())
times = x
for x in range(x):
    print((times - x ) *"X" )
```

I've lost an embarrassing amount of time on this..Hope you guys can help me.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add space in front:

```
for x in range(times):
    print(' '*x + 'X'*(times - x ))
```

output:

```
XXXXXXXXXX
 XXXXXXXXX
  XXXXXXXX
   XXXXXXX
    XXXXXX
     XXXXX
      XXXX
       XXX
        XX
         X
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pure string multiplying, you can resort to using [`str.rjust`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rjust.html):

```
for x in range(times, 0, -1):
    print((x*'x').rjust(times)

xxxxxxxx
 xxxxxxx
  xxxxxx
   xxxxx
    xxxx
     xxx
      xx
       x
```

Answer (score 0):

using `str.rjust()`

```
width = 10
for n in range(width, 0, -1):
    print(f'{"*" * n}'.rjust(width, ' '))
```

as an alternative, using string formatting:

```
print(f'{"*" * n: >{width}}')
```

f-strings require python 3.6+. as an alternative `str.format()` may be used.